# How to display ttl dataset as graph of node relationships in ckan

Tags: rdf, ckan, turtle-rdf

A bit of a newbie question, I can create datasets uploading ttl files, and can visualize a text using webpage_view plugin.

What I was wondering if it is possible to visualize a graph of relationships of the triples.

I am using Ckan 2.8.2, following is a TTL sample (from "Learning SPARQL" book) I am using:

```
# filename: ex012.ttl

@prefix ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> .
@prefix d:  <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#> .

d:i0432 ab:firstName "Richard" . 
d:i0432 ab:lastName  "Mutt" . 
d:i0432 ab:homeTel   "(229) 276-5135" .
d:i0432 ab:email     "richard49@hotmail.com" . 

d:i9771 ab:firstName "Cindy" . 
d:i9771 ab:lastName  "Marshall" . 
d:i9771 ab:homeTel   "(245) 646-5488" . 
d:i9771 ab:email     "cindym@gmail.com" . 

d:i8301 ab:firstName "Craig" . 
d:i8301 ab:lastName  "Ellis" . 
d:i8301 ab:email     "craigellis@yahoo.com" . 
d:i8301 ab:email     "c.ellis@usairwaysgroup.com" .
```

Or if this is possible to do at all in CKAN?

Comment: you need some extra tool. There are plenty of RDF visualization tools, first Google hit was by the way: https://www.w3.org/2018/09/rdf-data-viz/  there are also  VOWL and others